# Constructor/Function overload signature lookup time complexity?

Tags: constructor, compilation, language-agnostic, initialization, overloading

I was reading up on the `std::string` class in `C++` and noticed there are quite a few different constructors available giving us a wide set of initialization features. This got me wondering how a compiler picks which constructor to choose when given parameters, or in the case of overloads, how a compiler matches a function signature with a given set of parameters.

If we have the following functions declared in pseudo-code:

```
function f1(int numberHere) {
    //....do something
}

function f1(int numberHere, string stringHere) {
    //....do something
}
```

And I decide to call `f1(4)`, there are obviously two options to choose from, but what if there are 10000 options/signatures? Would it take proportionally longer? If so, what takes longer? Does the compiler have some sneaky `O(n)` way to index overloads such that it can call the right one in `O(1)` time once the program is running or would it compile in `O(1)` no matter how many overloads exist but take longer to run the finished result because of on-the-fly signature matching?

Can this question even be answered effectively?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matching function signatures is actually not different from any other search or lookup problem. There are three basic ways to do it depending on the data structure you are storing the available function signatures in:

1. Use an unsorted list or array and get O(n) time complexity.
2. Use a sorted array or a tree-like structure and get O(log(n)). (You can sort by type of 1st argument, then 2nd and so on, assuming that each type has an integer id assigned to it.)
3. Use a hash map and get O(1).

But I doubt that time complxity has any practical relevance in this case. It describes the asymptotic behaviour of algorithms for large values of n. Even for n=100, an unsorted array search might be faster than hash map lookup because it has less overhead.

And from a usability point of view it is a very bad idea to design an API having functions with 10 or even 100 overloads.

Comment: Agreed, no product will be usable if it applies to this question lol